# If $x^2yz^3 = 7^3$ and $xy^2 = 7^9$, what are the values of $xyz$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, exponentiation

My math teacher gave our class a challenge question today on exponents, but none of us have any idea how to solve it. We've tried linear systems, but it never quite worked out. Any ideas?

Comment: What has this to do with `linear-algebra`?

Comment: Take log to convert it into system of linear equations.

Comment: Hint:  just multiply the two equations together.

Comment: The point of a challenge problem is to solve it by yourself, not to ask someone on the internet to solve it for you...

Answer (score 5):

The quickest way is probably $$(x^2yz^3)(xy^2)=(7^3)(7^9)\Leftrightarrow x^3y^3z^3=7^{12}\Leftrightarrow(xyz)^3=(7^4)^3\Rightarrow xyz=7^4.$$

Let's try another (more general) strategy:
Since $a^b=e^{b\operatorname{ln}(a)},$ we can write the given equations as
$$x^2yz^3
=e^{2\operatorname{ln}(x)}e^{\operatorname{ln}(y)}e^{3\operatorname{ln}(z)}
=e^{2\operatorname{ln}(x)+\operatorname{ln}(y)+3\operatorname{ln}(z)}
=7^3
=e^{3\operatorname{ln}(7)}$$

and

$$xy^2
=e^{\operatorname{ln}(x)}e^{2\operatorname{ln}(y)}
=e^{\operatorname{ln}(x)+2\operatorname{ln}(y)}
=7^9
=e^{9\operatorname{ln}(7)}.$$

That is, setting $a_1:=\operatorname{ln}(x),a_2:=\operatorname{ln}(y)$ and $a_3:=\operatorname{ln}(z),$ we get the system of linear equations

$$2a_1+a_2+3a_3=3\operatorname{ln}(7)$$
$$a_1+2a_2=9\operatorname{ln}(7)$$

or in matrix notation

$$
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}_{=:A}
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\a_2\\a_3
\end{pmatrix}}_{=: b}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
3\operatorname{ln}(7)\\
9\operatorname{ln}(7)\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{=:c}.
$$
For the solution of this equation, we can use the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $A$, which leads to
$$b=A^T(A\cdot A^T)^{-1}c
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9}\\
-\frac{1}{18} & \frac{4}{9}\\
\frac{5}{18} & -\frac{2}{9}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
3\operatorname{ln}(7)\\
9\operatorname{ln}(7)\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{4}{3}\operatorname{ln}(7)\\
\frac{23}{6}\operatorname{ln}(7)\\
-\frac{7}{6}\operatorname{ln}(7)\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This means $a_1=\operatorname{ln}(x)=\frac{4}{3}\operatorname{ln}(7),$ i.e. $x=e^{a_1}=7^{\frac{4}{3}}.$ Similarly we get $y=7^{\frac{23}{6}}$
and $z=7^{-\frac{7}{6}}.$ We can now compute
$$xyz=7^{\frac{4}{3}}7^{\frac{23}{6}}7^{-\frac{7}{6}}=7^{\frac{24}{6}}=7^4.$$

Edit: Note, that there are other solutions to the matrix-equation by taking different pseudo-inverses of $A$. Thus, the values for $x,y$ and $z$ are not unique (but the result of $xyz$ is).

Comment: I'd write this as $(xyz)^3=x^3y^3z^3=(x^2yz^3)(xy^2)=(7^3)(7^9)=7^{12}=(7^4)^3\Rightarrow xyz=7^4$

Comment: Same thing (matter of taste)

Comment: Well, I'd say it's a matter of style. In my way, the sequence of equalities shows the flow of the argument and every equality can be clearly justified.

Comment: I should have used the iff-symbol instead of certain equal-signs. Changed that, and it should now underline my 'flow of the argument' (which hasn't changed). Satisfied?

Comment: Oh, much clearer now how your argument goes. It's a different from mine. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2yx^3\cdot xy^2=x^3y^3z^3=(xyz)^3=7^{12}$$
hence $$xyz=\sqrt[3]{7^{12}}=7^4=2401$$

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in one of the comments, taking the (natural) **logarithms**, we obtain a system of $2$ linear equations in variables $\ln(x)$, $\ln(y)$ and $\ln(z)$. Its augmented matrix is the following

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 2 & 1 & 3 & 3 \ln (7)\\ 1 & 2 & 0 & 9 \ln(7)\end{array}\right]$$

Using Gaussian elimination, we obtain the following row-reduced augmented matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 0 & 2 & - \ln(7)\\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 5 \ln(7)\end{array}\right]$$

Let $t := \ln(z)$ parameterize the solution set (a curve) in the positive octant. Hence,

$$\begin{array}{rl} \ln (x) &= - 2 t - \ln (7)\\ \ln (y) &= t + 5 \ln (7)\end{array}$$

and, thus,

$$\begin{array}{rl} x &= \frac 17 \, e^{-2t}\\ y &= 7^5 e^{t}\\ z &= e^t\end{array}$$

Lastly,

$$\boxed{ \,\\ \,\quad x y z = 7^4 \quad \\}$$